# How to avoid duplicates in JOIN MS-ACCESS (Room access management)

Tags: delphi, ms-access

This is for room access management, I have csv file exported from may external device this is the raw data:

```
2019.05.31  20:20:28    p+  462 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:23:35    p-  462 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:24:05    p+  461 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:24:13    p-  461 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:24:40    p+  460 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:24:51    p-  460 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:25:31    p+  447 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:25:36    p-  447 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:26:14    p+  459 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:26:42    p+  458 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:26:46    p-  458 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:27:49    p+  443 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:28:01    p-  443 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:28:16    p+  443 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:28:21    p-  443 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:29:05    p+  445 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
2019.05.31  20:29:09    p-  445 SALES MGR, ROVING GUARD
```

Note: P+ stands for entered room while P- for exit room

After downloading it, I will import the csv file to my application then separate the P+ and P- finally log it to database. This is the database structure:

[DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P1CL.png)
[P+ Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afcN8.png)
[P- Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lySKp.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWerJ.png)
as we can see, the records where duplicated and not correct compare to  the raw data, please help me to solve this problem or suggest another way to do this. Thanks.

BTW here is the query i used to get the result:

```
SELECT tblActivityPP.DateLog AS DateIN,
tblActivityPN.DateLog AS DateOUT, 
tblActivityPP.TimeLog AS TimeIN, 
tblActivityPN.TimeLog AS TimeOUT, 
tblActivityPP.Room,  
tblActivityPN.Room AS RoomOut, 
tblActivityPP.Position, 
tblActivityPP.Account, 
tblActivityPN.ID, 
tblActivityPP.ID
FROM tblActivityPP 
LEFT JOIN 
tblActivityPN ON 
(tblActivityPP.Position = tblActivityPN.Position) 
AND 
(tblActivityPP.Room = tblActivityPN.Room) 
AND 
(tblActivityPP.[Account] = tblActivityPN.[Account])
```

Comment: Please show data (P+Table, P-Table and Result) in table format (like raw data) not image! https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 1):

For distinct result you need DISTINCT clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
tblActivityPP.DateLog AS DateIN,
tblActivityPN.DateLog AS DateOUT, 
tblActivityPP.TimeLog AS TimeIN, 
tblActivityPN.TimeLog AS TimeOUT, 
tblActivityPP.Room,  
tblActivityPN.Room AS RoomOut, 
tblActivityPP.Position, 
tblActivityPP.Account, 
tblActivityPN.ID, 
tblActivityPP.ID
FROM tblActivityPP 
LEFT JOIN 
tblActivityPN ON 
(tblActivityPP.Position = tblActivityPN.Position) 
AND 
(tblActivityPP.Room = tblActivityPN.Room) 
AND 
(tblActivityPP.[Account] = tblActivityPN.[Account])
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is correct, but room 443 was entered/left three times.

```
| 2019.05.31 | 20:27:49 | p+ | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |
| 2019.05.31 | 20:28:01 | p- | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |
| 2019.05.31 | 20:28:16 | p+ | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |
| 2019.05.31 | 20:28:21 | p- | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |
...
| 2019.05.31 | 20:30    | p+ | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |  (this data is from image P+)
| 2019.05.31 | 20:30    | p- | 443 | SALES MGR | ROVING GUARD |  (this data is from image P-)
```

That leads to 9(3 rows in tblActivityPP * 3 rows in tblActivityPN) rows for room 443 if you join tblActivityPP and tblActivityPN on room. Correct result (each row in tblActivityPP is connected to each row in tblActivityPN), but not what you want

You want to know when room was left after entering. That is the first leave, after entered, what limits data to one row.

Don't create 2 tables (tables with same fieldnames usually should be one table with an additional field, where the property described by the tablenames is stored), just import the raw data to one table (e.g.`ÀctivityLog`) (but only one field for date and time (datetime)), create a table`Accounts`and store the PK(PrimaryKey) as FK(ForeignKey) in table, skip`Position`(should be stored in`Account`table) and create table`Activity`for entered/left room and store PK (as FK) instead of P+/P-. `

E.g table ÀctivityLog:

```
| Timestamp           | ActivityID | Room | AccountID |
|---------------------|:----------:|:----:|:---------:|
| 2019.05.31 20:20:28 |      1     |  462 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:23:35 |      2     |  462 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:24:05 |      1     |  461 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:24:13 |      2     |  461 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:24:40 |      1     |  460 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:24:51 |      2     |  460 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:25:31 |      1     |  447 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:25:36 |      2     |  447 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:26:14 |      1     |  459 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:26:42 |      1     |  458 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:26:46 |      2     |  458 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:27:49 |      1     |  443 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:28:01 |      2     |  443 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:28:16 |      1     |  443 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:28:21 |      2     |  443 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:29:05 |      1     |  445 |     1     |
| 2019.05.31 20:29:09 |      2     |  445 |     1     |
```

All fields should be indexed.

table`Activities`:

```
| ID | ActivityName | ActivityDescription |
|----|:------------:|---------------------|
| 1  |      P+      | Room entered        |
| 2  |      P-      | Room left           |
```

table`Accounts`:

```
| ID | AccountName  | PositionID                                       |
|----|--------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | ROVING GUARD | 3 (FK for Position SALES MGR in table Positions) |
```

All`ID`-Fields are PrimaryKey and Autoincrement.

Then create 2 queries as replacement for`tblActivityPP`/`tblActivityPN`by filtering`ActivityLog`for`ActivityID`.

qryEnterActivities:

```sql
SELECT ActivityLog.ID
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS DateLog
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "HH:nn") AS TimeLog
    ,Activites.ActivityName
    ,ActivityLog.Room
    ,Positions.PositionName AS Position
    ,Accounts.AccountName AS Account
FROM ActivitiesLog
INNER JOIN Activities ON ActivityLog.ActivityID = Activities.ID
INNER JOIN Accounts ON ActivityLog.AccountID = Accounts.ID
INNER JOIN Positions ON Accounts.PositionID = Positions.ID
WHERE ActivityLog.ActivityID = 1;
```

qryLeaveActivities:

```sql
SELECT ActivityLog.ID
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS DateLog
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "HH:nn") AS TimeLog
    ,Activites.ActivityName
    ,ActivityLog.Room
    ,Positions.PositionName AS Position
    ,Accounts.AccountName AS Account
FROM ActivitiesLog
INNER JOIN Activities ON ActivityLog.ActivityID = Activities.ID
INNER JOIN Accounts ON ActivityLog.AccountID = Accounts.ID
INNER JOIN Positions ON Accounts.PositionID = Positions.ID
WHERE ActivityLog.ActivityID = 2;
```

Your result query:

```sql
SELECT ActivityLog.ID
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS DateIN
    ,Format(ActivityLog.Timestamp, "HH:nn") AS TimeIn,
    ,(SELECT Min(Timestamp) FROM ActivityLog AS ALog WHERE ALog.AccountID = ActivityLog.AccountID AND ALOG.Timestamp > ActivityLog.Timestamp AND ALog.ActivityID = 2) as TimestampOut
    ,Format(TimestampOut, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS DateOut
    ,Format(TimestampOut, "HH:nn") AS TimeOut
    ,Activites.ActivityName
    ,ActivityLog.Room
    ,Positions.PositionName AS Position
    ,Accounts.AccountName AS Account
FROM ActivitiesLog 
INNER JOIN Activities ON ActivityLog.ActivityID = Activities.ID
INNER JOIN Accounts ON ActivityLog.AccountID = Accounts.ID
INNER JOIN Positions ON Accounts.PositionID = Positions.ID
WHERE ActivityLog.ActivityID = 1;
```

This fetches all room entered events and (sub)selects the next room left event for that account.

**All** SQL-Code is not tested and is missing parentheses, aliases, ..., but should show the general approach.